# what is Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib. while running pyspark in MacOs?

Tags: macos, pyspark, python-3.6

Pyspark is installed in my Mac. This error I am getting while I try to run Pyspark from the command line.

I am installing Pyspark using homebrew and following instructions in this blog(https://medium.com/@roshinijohri/spark-with-jupyter-notebook-on-macos-2-0-0-and-higher-c61b971b5007).
When I start running Pyspark in the shell I am getting the following error.

```
    Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
    [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib.
```

Answer (score 9):

MKL is Intel's "Math Kernel Library", and it basically handles calculations.
The new version of Numpy uses MKL by default, and that is likely why this error is showing up.

Try to update numpy,

```
conda update numpy
```

or disable MKL by

```
conda install nomkl
```

Hope that helped!
Reference:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3884

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I tried all the solutions above and neither of them solved this issue for me. For the folks that have a similar situation to me, I'm writing the solution that solved this bug below.

In my case, I have an anaconda virtual environment and doing all of the stuff in there.

Instead of removing mkl, or installing nomkl and etc. I installed it again by using the command:

```
conda install -c anaconda mkl
```

This solved the issue for me which I'm trying to solve for a day. I hope it also would be useful for you folks too.

Comment: Oh, you are sooo welcome. You also made my day haha!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Update your mkl package. That should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error. Then I tried to create a virtual environment and then this error went off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error after running `makemigrations` command in Django, it is highly likely that your virtual environment is not activated.

This happens because when the `venv` is not activated, python starts wondering off to other directories looking for different libraries.

Running `source venv/bin/activate` (where **venv** is name of your virtual environment) fixes issue

Answer (score 0):

Unconventionally try running your application that requires the `mkl` library outside the conda environment.