# Why do I get an MKL error when running my python script on MacOS

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, intel-mkl

I have a python script that was converted from an .ipynb notebook from Google Colab that I'm trying to run natively on my Mac running Big Sur.

When I try to run the script using python scriptname.py it gives me the following error:

```
NTEL MKL ERROR: dlopen(/Users/MyUser/opt/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_core.dylib, 9): image not found.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib.
```

It occurs immediately after I try to `import pandas`.

I tried `conda update numpy` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778337/what-is-intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-libmkl-core-dylib-while-running-pysp) but the problem persists.

I wondered if I didn't have pandas installed but I did `pip install pandas` and I got `Requirement already satisfied` for all 6 packages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. `numpy` also gave me the same problem so I uninstalled it `pip uninstall numpy` and reinstalled it `pip install numpy`.

I suppose I'll have to do this with all packages as I use them, but perhaps `pyenv` will provide a useful solution to my problem if. ever get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try following, to make sure it's not something with your `conda` stuff.

```
> python3 -m venv venv-38
> source venv-38/bin/activate
(venv-38) > pip3 install pandas
...
...
(venv-38) > python
Python 3.8.1 (v3.8.1:1b293b6006, Dec 18 2019, 14:08:53)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> quit()
```

** Update **

You can easily reuse this environment in all future terminal sessions. Let's say you have this `venv-38` inside `$HOME`. All you have to do is to open terminal session, and then

```
> source $HOME/venv-38/bin/activate
```

since now, your `Python` environment will be used as if it was installed inside `venv-38` directory.

Comment: This fixes the problem but as soon as I open a new terminal window I get the same problem again. Is there a way I can make this fix permanent?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough to open your session and then, type in: `source venv-38/bin/activate`. You can add explicit path as well.

Comment: That's useful, but is there a way to get it to work automatically without having to use a python virtual environment? I'd like it to be as automated as possible!