# Huggingface models gives Intel MKL FATAL ERROR on Apple M1 processor

Tags: conda, apple-m1, huggingface-transformers

On MacBook Pro with M1 Pro processor running macOS Monterey (12.4) and Python 3.9, I am getting the following error

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel(R) SSSE3) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
```

---

I applied the solutions from these similar questions

- updating [numpy and updating/disabling MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778337/what-is-intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-libmkl-core-dylib-while-running-pysp/57024288#57024288)
- uninstalling [PyTorch and reinstalling from pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830755/intel-mkl-fatal-error-this-system-does-not-meet-the-minimum-requirements-for-us)
- installing [nkml and torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306262/conda-env-broken-after-installing-pytorch-on-m1-intel-mkl-fatal-error)

and re-installed the necessary packages (as shown from the output of `conda list`). However I am still getting the same error.

```
ipykernel (6.15.2), 
numpy (1.22.4), 
pandas (1.4.3), 
matplotlib(3.5.3), 
nomkl (1.0), 
pytorch (1.12.1), 
torchvisio(0.11.3), 
nomkl (1.0)
```

Comment: The last one does not seem to have worked. can you share the output of `conda list`?

Comment: After applying the answers from the last one, these packages were downloaded ipykernel (6.15.2), (1.0.0), numpy (1.22.4), pandas (1.4.3), matplotlib(3.5.3), nomkl (1.0), pytorch (1.12.1), torchvisio(0.11.3), nomkl (1.0)

Comment: Please edit question to include (nicely formatted) requested info, rather than commenting. Use comments to notify others when you update the question body.

Comment: Question updated with the output of conda list

Comment: Forgive me if this is off base, but isn't the M1 a strict Apple chip?  Sure its ARC architecture to allow you to run a parallel copy of Windows WHILE you are running your MacOS via a something like the software called Parallels.  But I wonder, if the error is giving "Intel" issues, if its a "Microsoft" comparability issue?    I don't have a solution but I think I have the ballpark you are looking for.  UPDATE - have you tried using Parallels and doing this inside a Windows environment to see if that software can emulate the hardware support its looking for?

Comment: Same environment (with exact library versions) on an Intel-based Mac didn't give an error. I also tried running the project on Windows using Parallels on M1 Mac but I had different issues